# Java RMI with Callable

Tags: java, rmi, callable

I have a server and several clients. The server should be able to delegate tasks to the clients so I tried to implement RMI. I followed [this](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2012/01/a-simple-java-rmi-tutorial/) tutorial and everything is working fine if I use String as param- and/or return-value.

Now the server should send undefined tasks to the clients so I tried to use a Callable as param but the program crashed with a `NotSerializableException`. Since Callable doesn't implement the Serializeable interface thats the result I expected.

Now I found several sources that use Callable and Runnable as params and that confuses me. Is there any trick to get it to work? Or do i miss something important? Maybe theres a technology that fits better?

[Resource1](http://homepages.thm.de/~hg51/Veranstaltungen/NVP/Folien/nvp-09.pdf) S. 33

[Resource2](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193k/handouts993/14RMI2.pdf) s. 5

And heres my code:

```
// Client
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    App app = new App();
    app.startClient();
    Thread.sleep(20000);//just for test purpose
}
private void startClient() {
    try {
        // create on port 1099
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        // create a new service named myMessage
        registry.rebind("calcClient", new CalculateRemoteImpl<String>());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("System is ready");
}
// RemoteInterface
public interface CalculateRemote<T> extends Remote {
    public T hello(Callable<T> hello) throws RemoteException;
}
// RemoteInterfaceImpl
public class CalculateRemoteImpl<T> extends UnicastRemoteObject implements CalculateRemote<T> {
    public T hello(Callable<T> hello) throws RemoteException {
        return (T) ("Hello " + hello);// just print address of object
    }
}
```

.

```
// Server
public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    app.doTest();
}
private void doTest() {
    try {
        // fire to localhost port 1099
        Registry myRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
        // search for myMessage service
        CalculateRemote<String> impl = (CalculateRemote<String>) myRegistry.lookup("calcClient");
        // call server's method         
        System.out.println("Message: " + impl.hello(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws RemoteException, Exception {
                return "hello";
            }
        }));
        System.out.println("Message Sent");
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// And the same RemoteInterface
public interface CalculateRemote<T> extends Remote {
    public T hello(Callable<T> hello) throws RemoteException;
}
```

.

```
// stacktrace
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: de.fhb.rmicalcserver.App$1
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:156)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at $Proxy0.hello(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhb.rmicalcserver.App.doTest(App.java:30)
    at de.fhb.rmicalcserver.App.main(App.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: de.fhb.rmicalcserver.App$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:292)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:151)
```

Comment: `Callable` is just an interface, so that isn't directly your problem.  You should be able to implement callable on an object as long as it is also properly serializable.  but it looks like you're trying to send executable code to the other side?

Comment: Jep that should be the clue ;)

Comment: while possible, I think it isn't as easy as what you've shown.  you'd have to serialize the code itself as a .class (along with any +all references! along with any super types), you'd probably need a custom class loader on the other side to properly load the classes (and references?)

Comment: ah.. if i wrap that callable in a class and as long as i publish it on both sides it works. Since its not what i want i have to implement some Classloaders i guess. Do i have to serialize the java-classes too? At the moment the project isnt bigger then what i showed :) Can you recommend some good tutorials on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send objects to clients whose classes aren't deployed at the client you need to take a long look at the RMI codebase feature.